# jQuery: Check the value of the attribute 'Value' and change

Tags: jquery, button, attributes, attr

I am trying to set the value of a button on click to change every time. If the value is 'Accept' make it 'Cancel' and vice versa.

Currently I have: `$('button').attr({ value:"Accept"})`.

Now this sets the button's value to Accept. I want to do something:

**If Attribute value = 'Accept', make it 'Decline' else make it 'Accept'.**

Thanks alot

Comment: Don't think attr has that signature! http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Guess I should have read my own link eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( button ).click( function () {
    this.value = this.value === 'Accept' ? 'Decline' : 'Accept';
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kF378/1/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an if/then statement in your click handler that checks for the current state of the button and then sets it accordingly.

```
$('button').bind('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('value') == 'Accept') {
        $this.attr('value', 'Decline');
    } else {
        $this.attr('value', 'Accept');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sime's answer is probably better, but I'll post this for fun:

```
var invert = {
    "Accept": "Decline",
    "Decline": "Accept"
};

$('#foo').click( function () {
    this.value = invert[this.value];
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb7u5/1/)